# How to access json data in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have complex json data. It can be in either formats as below :

```
1. {"Physics":{"5b87ceb691":"Motion","5b87ce3e":"Mass"}} //where value itself is a json
2. {"a60a8001805":"Finish chapter 1","a60a8002ab0":"Finish assignments"} //simple key value pair
```

I want to create checkboxes for all values (`Motion`, `Mass`, `Finish chapter 1`, `Finish assignments` for above examples) and keys should come like text in between those checkboxes (`Physics` for above example) (Key should come like text only if it's value is a json object, since `Physics`'s value is a json, `Physics` should show like a text and in example 2, since there are no such keys whose value is a json object, no key will show like a text).

I've implemented this in javascript in the following way :

```
var str = "";
if(Object.keys(data).length !== 0) {
var i = 1;
for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var val = data[key];
    if(typeof val == 'object') {
      str += '<div class = "data_text hidden">' + key + '</div>';
      for (var subKey in val) {
        if (val.hasOwnProperty(subKey)) {
          var subValue = val[subKey];
          str += '<div class="db-checkbox data_options hidden"><input type="checkbox" name="abc" id="' + i + '"><label for="' + i + '">' + subValue + '</label></div>'
          i += 1;
        }
      }
   } else {
    str += '<div class="db-checkbox data_options hidden"><input type="checkbox" name="abc" id="' + i + '"><label for="' + i + '">' + val + '</label></div>'
    i += 1;
   }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to do the same in php. I searched to find out the way to access json data in php, but all of those works only when keys are known. (For example, `data->a60a8002ab0`) But I want to do this generically. Don't want to hardcode anything. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: start with [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and write code from there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

Try `json_decode` in associative mode by passing in the second param true so that it returns an associative array that you can loop through, similar to your javascript code.

Comment: I am very new to php, can you like give me an example of your approach?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
//try each of the following by comment/uncomment
//$myjson = '{"Physics":{"5b87ceb691":"Motion","5b87ce3e":"Mass"}}';
//$myjson = '{"a60a8001805":"Finish chapter 1","a60a8002ab0":"Finish assignments"}';
$myjson = '{"a60a8001805":"Finish chapter 1","a60a8002ab0":"Finish assignments","Physics":{"5b87ceb691":"Motion","5b87ce3e":"Mass"}}';

$json_md_ary = json_decode($myjson,true);
$i=1;
foreach($json_md_ary as $key=>$val){
    if (is_array($val)){
        echo $key, "<br>";
        foreach($val as $k=>$v){
            echo $k, ' => ' ,$v,'<input type="checkbox" name="abc" id="'.$i.'">',"<br>";
            $i++;
        }
    }else{
        echo $key, ' => ' ,$val,'<input type="checkbox" name="abc" id="'.$i.'">',"<br>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsondata = '{"Physics":{"5b87ceb691":"Motion","5b87ce3e":"Mass"}}';

$data = json_decode($jsondata);
 
foreach($data as $key => $val){
   print_r($val);
}
```